# Using grep number as variable is not working

Tags: linux, variables, unix, grep, command

I want to grep a number of file in the current directory on linux.

```
E = $( grep -F "TOTEN" OUTCAR | tail -1 | awk '{printf "%12.9f \n",$5}')
```

When I run the script, it keeps telling me the command is not found.
I tried many ways to solve it by searching online but it did't work.

Comment: Remove spaces around `=` first

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  Instead of `grep -F "TOTEN" OUTCAR | tail -1 | awk '{printf "%12.9f \n",$5}'`, just write `awk '/TOTEN/{k=sprintf("%12.9f",$5)} END{print k}' OUTCAR`